# rosdep init failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I enter `sudo rosdep init`  then output:

```
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
```

---

Edit:

```
jeff@ubuntu:~$ sudo easy_install -U rosdep rospkg
Searching for rosdep
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/rosdep/
Best match: rosdep 0.11.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rosdep/rosdep-0.11.4.tar.gz#md5=c8969f199b0590338bf20dab63bc4d50
error: Download error for https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rosdep/rosdep-0.11.4.tar.gz#md5=c8969f199b0590338bf20dab63bc4d50: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228703/rosdep-init-failed/) by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please just try again, this is most likely a transient ((inter)network) error.

If you already did that, then please update your question with what actions you've already taken to resolve this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-11**:
I have tried again, but failed! It's the same error

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-11**:
I did not say you should *reinstall*, I said you should try to run `sudo rosdep init` again ..

Also: please install `rosdep` using `apt-get` instead of `pip` or `easy_install` (unless you really have to). It will probably result in hard to solve problems later on.

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-11**:
I entered sudo rosdep init again, but ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list.I live in shenzh,china,Is this website not support this area like china?It,s urgent for me to solve it ,please help me！

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-12**:
What is the output of `wget https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`?

> live in shenzh,china,Is this website not support this area like china?

It should work fine, unless there is someone/something interfering with your network. Do you use a proxy?

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-12**:
no ,I tried several times,but it does  still not work? I don't why,any other ways to solve it?

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-12**:
Is that used to initialize for the "rosdep init" a package,if yes,please download and send it to me at 1472787567@qq.com,my ROS indigo is installed on ubuntu14.04 LTS! thank you

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-12**:
So, what is the output of `wget https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`?

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-12**:
I don't know about this,luckily my problem has been solved, thanks for your attention!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-13**:
So, what was the solution in the end (and the cause)?